# How can I use FOUND_ROWS() function in PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

Already, when I was using `mysql_query`, I used `FOUND_ROWS()` function like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Users';
mysql_query($query);
$query = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()';
mysql_query($query);
```

---

Now I use PDO and here is my query:

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
                                   u.id user_id,
                                   u.avatar,
                                   u.date_time,
                                   CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname) name,
                                   sum($this->table_alias.vote_value) vote_value,
                                   sum($this->table_alias.score) score,
                                   $category_in_the_select AS tc $tag_in_the_select AS tt
                            FROM users u
                            JOIN reputations $this->table_alias ON u.id = $this->table_alias.owner_id $query_join
                            WHERE $time_limitation $query_where
                            GROUP BY user_id, u.avatar, u.date_time, name, tc, tt
                            ORDER BY score DESC, vote_value DESC
                            LIMIT :j, $this->per_page");
$this->parameters[":j"] = $j;
$sth->execute($this->parameters);
$users = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As you can see, I've used `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the `SELECT` statement and I want to know how can I use `FOUND_ROWS()`?

Comment: maybe the same `$this->dbh->exec('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Honestly still I stuck on it. The link you provided doesn't work in my case. When I combine `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` with `$query` variable, it throws `Syntax error or access violation`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to count the number of all matched rows before limiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is run a `->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')` after your original execute.

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
                                   u.id user_id,
                                   u.avatar,
                                   u.date_time,
                                   CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname) name,
                                   sum($this->table_alias.vote_value) vote_value,
                                   sum($this->table_alias.score) score,
                                   $category_in_the_select AS tc $tag_in_the_select AS tt
                            FROM users u
                            JOIN reputations $this->table_alias ON u.id = $this->table_alias.owner_id $query_join
                            WHERE $time_limitation $query_where
                            GROUP BY user_id, u.avatar, u.date_time, name, tc, tt
                            ORDER BY score DESC, vote_value DESC
                            LIMIT :j, $this->per_page");
$this->parameters[":j"] = $j;
$sth->execute($this->parameters);
$users = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = $this->dbh->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Thx, but `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' `

Comment: And when I remove one of `->`, then `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; `

Comment: Really? Odd! For me it throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elkfC.png)

Comment: `:-)` .. Sorry to ask, what does *PHEW* mean?

Comment: :) PHEW = thank heavans for that,thought I was losing it :)